# Homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

I have just shown that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a principal ideal ring, by using (1) a previously proven result that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain (and hence a principal ideal ring), and (2) the result that the image of a principal ideal ring under a ring endomorphism (in this case, the canonical epimorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $a \mapsto a + n\mathbb{Z} \simeq m\mathbb{Z}, \, m \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$) is also a principal ideal ring.

By this result (or rather as a consequence of the proof of this result), I determined that ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are of the form $f(n\mathbb{Z})$, so does that mean that all the ideals are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ as described above in my mention of the canonical epimorphism?

Now, by the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings, Extended Version, the possible homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}/I$, where $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So, once I know how to correctly write down the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, I should be able to describe completely all homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, which is what I am looking to do here.

So I suppose my question here is twofold: (1) Have I correctly identified/described the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ here? If not, what should I change? And (2) Once I have correctly done that, is it enough to just say that all homomorphic images are $\mathbb{Z}_{n}/I$ where the $I$ are those ideals, or is there a better way to express them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
By the Third Isomorphism Theorem, ideals $I$ of $\Z/n\Z$ are in bijection of ideals $J$ of $\Z$ that contain $(n)$, and furthermore, $(\Z/n\Z)/I \cong \Z/J$ under this correspondence. So now you just need to figure out what ideals of $\Z$ contain $(n)$.

Comment: how would I figure that out? $(n)$ consists of all finite sums of $mn$, right? Where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Comment: You know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal ring, which means all of its ideals are of the form $(n)$ for some $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. The elements of $(n)$ are exactly the multiples of $n$. That is, $\{0,\pm n, \pm 2n, \ldots \}$. When will this be contained in another ideal $(d)$?

Comment: When $n \vert d$?

Comment: If $n \vert d$, then $d = mn$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, which means that $d \in (n)$. But you want to know when $(n)$ is contained in $(d)$, which is equivalent to saying that $n \in (d)$.

Comment: so putting this all together, how does this tell me what the homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are again?

Comment: Okay, brain fart moment. It's because the ideals $I$ which I sought are the ones of the form $(d)$, so all homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are given by $\mathbb{Z}_{n}/(d)$.

Comment: The homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are things of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. But this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/J$ where $J$ is some ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $(n)$. These ideals are of the form $(d)$ where $d \vert n$.

Comment: yes, the stupid bug got me there for a second.

Comment: sorry, but I think it's got me again: You said the third isomorphism theorem. According to my notes, that's the one that says "Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of a ring and $I \subseteq J$. Then, $R/J \simeq (R/I)/(J/I)$". So, in your answer, $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, $(R/I)$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, and $(J/I)$ is just $I$?

Comment: If $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $R/I$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then shouldn't $I$ be $(n)$?

Comment: I suppose so. It doesn't say anything about $I$ being in bijection with $J$, though. Unless this is supposed to follow from that somehow.

Comment: Maybe you have it written down as another theorem, something like "ideals of $R/I$ are in bijection with ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the quotients work out how you would want"

Comment: unfortunately, ours just says that the "set of subrings of $R/I$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of subrings $S \subseteq R$ such that $I \subseteq S$. The correspondence is given by $S \mapsto S/I$. Moreover, $S$ is an ideal of $R$ if and only if $S/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$". I might try to adapt it to work for ideals and not just subrings.

Comment: but ideals are subrings, right? So maybe I can just use it without adaptation..

Comment: N/M found what I needed. Thanks for all your help! :)